# Google Speech API returns PERMISSION_DENIED the request cannot be identified with a client project

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

So i modified the `Google Speech API` Example code (didn't work before either) to be on par with their update notice (regarding the deprecation in `ClientAuthenticator` ) and get the same error as before with no resolution, with the host being `speech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/speech:asyncrecognize?key=My_Key` my code is as follows:

```
public static ManagedChannel createChannel(String host) throws IOException {
  FileInputStream filestream = new FileInputStream("/home/admin/creds.json");

  GoogleCredentials creds = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(filestream).createScoped(OAUTH2_SCOPES);

  ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(host).build();
  GreeterGrpc.GreeterStub stub = GreeterGrpc.newStub(channel);
  stub = stub.withCallCredentials(MoreCallCredentials.from(creds));
  System.out.println(channel.authority()+creds);

  filestream.close();

  return channel;
}
```

but it simply returns a

```
WARNING: RPC failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=The     request cannot be identified with a client project. Please pass a valid API key with the request., cause=null}
```

any help or advice is welcome, Thanks!

Comment: The code you've provided is using `GreeterGrpc` - shouldn't you be using the Speech API's stub? Where did you get `creds.json` from? (Is it definitely a service account JSON file? It should have JSON properties of `type`, `project_id`, `private_key_id`, `private_key`, `client_email`, `client_id`, `auth_uri`, `token_uri`, `auth_provider_x509_cert_url` and `client_x509_cert_url`)

Comment: @JonSkeet Its a valid JSON but idk how to use their stubs as i cant find examples or documentation

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/grpc - hopefully that'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

Hey instead of doing this,

> GreeterGrpc.GreeterStub stub = GreeterGrpc.newStub(channel);
>   stub = stub.withCallCredentials(MoreCallCredentials.from(creds));

please do following:

> GreeterGrpc.GreeterStub stub = GreeterGrpc.newStub(channel).withCallCredentials(MoreCallCredentials.from(creds));

As your code reinitiate the stub object, you are getting PERMISSION_DENIED.

I hope it helps.